# For simulating events, should one maintain a list of delegates or use multicast delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates

What are the differences between these two classes? Which is preferable?

```
class MulticastExample
{
    delegate void ME();

    ME me;

    public MulticastExample()
    {
        ME a = new ME(() => Console.WriteLine("A"));
        ME b = new ME(() => Console.WriteLine("B"));

        me = a + b;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        me();
    }
}
```

-

```
class ListExample
{
    delegate void LE();

    List<LE> le = new List<LE>();

    public ListExample()
    {
        LE a = new LE(() => Console.WriteLine("A"));
        LE b = new LE(() => Console.WriteLine("B"));

        le.Add(a);
        le.Add(b);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        foreach (var x in le)
        {
            x();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `MulticastExample`,a single call to `me` would call all the methods `subscribed` to it.So `a` and `b` would be called through a single call to `me`

With `ListExample` you would have to call each of the delegates individually.So you would have to individually invoke `a` and `b` which you **are** doing in the `foreach` loop

---

If `a` and `b` are going to refer to a single method of the same signature then `ListExample` is redundant.You should use `MulticastExample`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the first example. Note that you can always get a list of the items in your "multicast" delegate by saying `me.GetInvocationList()`. The type `MulticastExample.ME` inherits this method from `System.Delegate`.

When you assign to `a` and `b` you don't have to use `new` syntax. The same delegate is created by:

```
ME a = () => Console.WriteLine("A");
```

Note that each instance of `ME` is immutable and has a fixed-length invocation list. This list is guaranteed to contain at least one item.

When you "add" or "subtract" (combine or remove) delegates, the original instances are unchanged (immutability) and a new instance is created.

If the result of a "subtraction" like:

```
ME c = b - a;
```

would give a zero-length multicast delegate, no new instance is created, and a `null` reference is returned instead (i.e. `c` becomes `null`). So remember a `null` check before you invoke with: `c();`

If you choose to use `List<T>` instead, one difference is (as you can probably tell by now) that a `List<>` is mutable. Also note that it is your responsibility to check that no member of the `List<>` is in itself multicast, since *any* delegate type in .NET allows invocation lists of more than one item.

Finally (but I guess you know that) a delegate type like `ME` does not have to be nested inside some other type (in this case the `class` `MulticastExample`), but of course that's fine when you want the delegate type to be an "implementation detail" of the containing class.

If you plan to make your delegate type a generic type, don't make this type contravariant (or covariant which is less useful here) in any of its type parameters if you plan to combine with `+`.

Comment: Actually, the `List<LE>` approach works fine if multicast delegates are passed into the list, while the multicast approach can fall flat.  Assuming XY is the combination of X and Y, adding Y to a multicast delegate followed by XY, and then subtracting Y followed by XY, will leave X subscribed.  Using a `List<LE>`, by contrast, the attempt to subtract `Y` would correctly remove the `Y` that was added as a standalone item, rather than the one which is within `XY`.

Comment: @supercat Confirmed. It will leave a `Y` and an `X` on the internal invocation list of `System.Delegate`.

Comment: I wonder if there are any significant structural advantages to the way `MulticastDelegate` is implemented?  If I were designing the system, `Delegate` would have two fields, and `Delegate.Combine` would create a new delegate whose `Target` was an array of the proper delegate type, and whose `Method` was a static method that took such an array as a parameter.

Comment: Methods like `Delegate.Combine` could check whether either or both of the delegates being combined had a `Method` which was the "run-all" method and--if so--either create a new one whose array contained all the items in the original delegates, but methods that didn't want to worry about such details could assume `Method` and `Target` would suffice to define the delegate's behavior whether it was unicast or multicast.